# One value for multiple placeholders in nodejs-mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

To allow users to login using thier `username` or `email` OR `phonenumber`, I'm using this query:

```
res.post('/api/userlogin', function(req, res){
    connection.query(
        'SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=? OR email=? OR phonenumber=? AND password=?', 
        [req.body.loginfield, req.body.loginfield,req.body.loginfield, req.body.password], 
        function(){  
        ...
        ...
        //res.send
    });
});
```

I beleive this is how mysql work, but I thought maybe there is a way to use only one value (`req.body.loginfield`) for multiple placeholder without typing it repeatedly.

I couldn't find anything about it in the docs though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [the `IN` operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_in):

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE ? IN (username, email, phonenumber) AND password = ?
```

---

Side note: your original query has a *prescendence issue*, which makes it quite unsafe. As it is, this will authorize users that login using their username or email without checking their password, since this:

```
username=? OR email=? OR phonenumber=? AND password=?
```

Is syntaxically equivalent to:

```
(username=? OR email=?) OR (phonenumber=? AND password=?)
```

This is because logical operator `OR` has lower prescedence than `AND`. You would need to surround the `OR`ed conditions with parenthesis, as follows:

```
(username=? OR email=? OR phonenumber=?) AND password=?)
```

Comment: Amazing, using IN operator like this is new to me. Thanks for the side note too. precious informaitons.

Comment: Welcome @Dohab, happy to help!

Comment: @Dohab: is there any particular reason why you unaccepted the answer?

Comment: yeah sure, sorry for that, I just tested this and I get some unwanted result. When phonenumber is 0 (in the database) the row returned as a result even if username and email are not equal to ? placeholder.

Comment: I can add `AND phonenumber > 0`. This works, but I don't think it's practical.

Comment: @Dohab: what is the datatype of column `phonenumber` in the `users` table?

Comment: Datatype is INT(10)

Comment: OK. We need to convert that to a string for comparison; we can use `cast()` for that. `cast()` can't work within a `in` clause, so now we need two conditions: `WHERE (? IN (username, email) OR ? = cast(phonenumber as char(20))) or password = ?`

Comment: Now, the second `?` is not resolved unless I add another `req.body.loginfield` to db.query(). I'm sorry.

Comment: Yes absolutely. With this syntax you need to bind the variable twice.

Comment: Well, I think I'm going to change phonenumber datatype to varchar, since duplicating variables is the thing I'm trying to avoid XD.